# Incompatible Types, but it doesn't make sense(Java)

Tags: java, generics, iterator, incompatibletypeerror

I'm trying to iterate through a set and I want to save the next element in a temporary variable, but it is giving me a compilation error for incompatible types.

```
Iterator it = this.iterator();
E next = it.next();
```

next() returns a generic type E and next is of type E. Why is it giving me the error?

Comment: It makes sense. Pay attention to the error message - the hint should be something about `Object`.

Answer (score 5):

You're using `Iterator` as a raw type, since you haven't provided a type argument. When you use raw types, any related generic types become their [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6). In other words, any use of a class type variable in methods parameter, return types, etc. become either `Object` or the upper bound.

You probably want

```
Iterator<E> it = this.iterator();
E next = it.next();
```

if `this.iterator()` has a return type of `Iterator<E>`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't realize that. Thanks!

Comment: @user3391296 This isn't obvious at all. Type erasure is not a simple concept. Neither are raw types.

Answer (score 1):

You are using raw type iterator, use it with Generics, then it will allow to compile

```
Iterator<E> it = this.iterator();
E next = it.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generics or else typecast to Object.